# How do I compare a SQL Server datetime using just the date, not the time?

Tags: sql-server, datetime, sql-server-2012

I like to compare on 2 dates as following when I am doing a join:

```
    a.requestdate = b.alertDate
```

but I do not want to take the time into consideration. Just the date.

Wondering what the best way to do this would be. I am using SQL Server 2012 (t-sql)

Answer (score 1):

Or you can cast the fields to Dates.....but I prefer @ravindra's solution.

```
CAST(DateField1 AS DATE) = CAST(DateField2 AS DATE)
```

Answer (score 0):

In where condition, you can use [datediff](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx) function like this.

`datediff(day, a.requestdate, b.alertdate) = 0`

Answer (score 0):

Simple, if using Sql 2008 or above

```
Convert(date,requestdate) = Convert(date,alertdate)
```

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient if you're going to join on it is probably to create indexed computed columns with the dates, and join on them instead. Something like;

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  id INT,
  request_datetime DATETIME,
  request_date AS CAST(request_datetime AS DATE)
);

CREATE INDEX d_ix ON test(request_date);
```

This will allow the join to use exact matching on the index, and things should run faster.